# Go Project in IntelliJ Not Resolving Dependencies

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ CE and I just imported a Go project that I cloned from GitHub. On my Mac, I have some folder organization where I group projects that I work on based on the technologies. For example., in my Projects folder on my Mac, I have the following sub folders:

```
- go-projects
- scala-projects
- rust-projects
- ruby-projects
```

So I obviously checked out the Go project in the go-projects folder which looks like this:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:go-projects joe$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe  staff   102B Oct 28 07:51 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  19 joe  staff   646B Oct 24 06:48 golang-restful-starter-kit/
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe  staff   102B Oct 28 07:51 pkg/
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe  staff   102B Oct 27 10:23 src/
```

And if I get into the src folder, it looks like this:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:go-projects joe$ cd src
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 joe  staff   204B Nov  7 19:14 github.com/
Joes-MacBook-Pro:src joe$ cd github.com/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe  staff   102B Oct 28 08:20 btcsuite/
drwxr-xr-x  16 joe  staff   544B Nov  7 19:16 eth-client/
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe  staff   102B Oct 27 10:24 ethereum/
drwxr-xr-x   3 joe  staff   102B Oct 28 07:51 tools/
Joes-MacBook-Pro:github.com joe$
```

Here is my Go related environment settings:

```
# For Go projects, we set the GOPATH
export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
export GOPATH="/Users/joe/Projects/Private/go-projects"
export GODEPS="/Users/joe/Projects/Private/go-projects/bin/godep"
```

Now I import one of the Go project into IntelliJ and I get to see the following error saying that it is not able to resolve a directory as it can be seen in the screenshot below!

[image]

How can I get rid of this error? Any ideas?

Comment: Well, for one, your directory path doesn't match.  Your `ll` calls show eth-client in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/eth-client`, but you're trying to import it as `github.com/getamis/eth-client`.  The import coloration clearly shows where it starts failing to find the directory in the import path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For golang projects, it's good to have Goland installed ( also a product of JetBrains )[Goland Download](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/download/). Moreover for the above concern you can use:

```
go get *the_project_to_clone*
```

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that when I clone the project, I should not do a git clone but rather do:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint
```

Not sure why this is so, but after doing this my IntelliJ was able to resolve every file on my project!

Comment: `go get` calls `git clone`.  You can do either.  `go get` just simplifies it a bit.

Comment: This is probably unrelated. Also you should know that the IntelliJ CE plugin hasn't been updated in a year now and the development has moved into a dedicated Go IDE, https://www.jetbrains.com/go/